# wake up thread from readLine() (from System.in , No socket )

Tags: java, multithreading, nio, system.in

I have 2 Thread : **main** and **Thread2**.

**Main**-->create Thread2, sleep for 3 second, exit.

**Thread2**--> readline from System.in and exit.

**I want to wake up Thread2 if it is block in a readline()**, i don't want to use timeout, and closing the main inputstream by generating an exception in Thread2 don't work .

**The code :**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InterruptedIOException;

public class Main {    
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    InputStreamReader sc = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

    Thread2 t = new Thread2(sc);
    Thread tt = new Thread(t);
    tt.start();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("exit sleep");

    tt.interrupt();
    System.out.println("exit main");
  }
}

class Thread2 implements Runnable {
  InputStreamReader qst;

  public Thread2(InputStreamReader sc) {
    qst = sc;
  }  
  public void run() {
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(qst);
    try {
      System.out.println("read thread");

      buff.readLine(); //Here is locked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
      System.out.println("exit thread");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Execution (println)**:

-read Thread

(after 3 second)

-exit sleep

-exit main

But Thread2 non stop--> it is block in a readline. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your thread to deamon:

```
tt.setDaemon(true);
```

The doc says:

> Marks this thread as either a daemon thread or a user thread. The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.

In your case, tt will stop running when the main thread ends.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here:

1. As others have suggested, you somehow have to force-close your input stream
2. You can step back, and consider to re-design your whole thing: Java offers you techniques to do **non-blocking** IO. You can turn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099640/non-blocking-io-vs-async-io-and-implementation-in-java) for some first guidance how to do that.

Of course, it really depends on your context which of the two makes more sense. Option 2 of course means a very much different approach; but on the other hand: if you don't want to block on reads, then well: you should not block on reads.

Comment: thanks for the 2 point of the answers, the 1 point not work,  maybe because inputstrem is non-blocking, right?

Comment: @John There is no non-blocking I/O for `System.in`.