# AsynchronousServerSocketChannel vs ServerSocketChannel performance

Tags: java, java-io

I am wondering about the performance using ServerSocketChannel and  AsynchronousServerSocketChannel. In theory, AsynchronousServerSocketChannel should be faster. Do you know which option is better from a performance perspective?

Comment: Please precise: "performance"/use case/assumptions/circumstances/"benchmark"... otherwise your question appears "too broad" (to me)

Comment: I have an application where I have to handle multiple concurrent requests with a non-blocking approach, using a low number of threads as possible.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25099640/1564218) question, to understand the terms, especially "async", better. This should also clarify where/how you can make performance improvements and when not.